# Controlling TPM with C#

Tags: c#, tpm

I am trying to

- initialize the TPM
- set an owner
- create AIKs

Any help/link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Read MSDN.
TBS Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446794(VS.85).aspx
Using TBS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725663(v=VS.85).aspx
TBS Base Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446796(VS.85).aspx

You may also want to look at this article from MS about TPM, some of them with sample code:
Overview of TPM Management
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730635.aspx

Trusted Platform Module Management Step-by-Step Guide
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749022(WS.10).aspx

Understanding Keys and Passwords Used by the TPM
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755038.aspx

Comment: The question was about C#. Those links are all about TBS, a C++ library.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Microsoft's TPM library for C++ ('TBS') has no equivalent in .Net, but there's an external library from Microsoft that provides a binding - [TSS.Net](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSS.MSR)

The documentation lives in [a .docx file.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/master/Using%20the%20TSS.Net%20Library.docx)

Answer (score 2):

It's a really old question...

But, for anyone looking for it now-days, There's a C# solution for TPM 2.0 in GitHub:

https://github.com/ms-iot/security/tree/master/Limpet