# how to enable TPM measured boot and see pcr values in windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, tpm, trusted-computing

How can I enable TPM measured boot in Windows 10?

I want the TPM hashes to be captured in PCR values and I want to be able to see the results. I know how to do it in Linux but I don't know what should I do in Windows.

I found the following guides, but they don't seem to have the information I need:

- On the Microsoft website there is a guide:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/trustedplatformmodule/get-tpm?view=win10-ps
  but it's only for very basic tasks and doesn't explain this.
- I also saw this:
  [TPM PCR Generation in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180166/tpm-pcr-generation-in-windows) but it's not what I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you give me negative score? why? why? answer rapidly. i want to know why

Comment: The question is very vague, include how you do it in linux, an example of what you get and maybe then someone will try to answer it.

Comment: In Windows at least, you'd normally enable TPM in your firmware settings. But the question about how to see the results generated by TPM is very useful, and so is the answer by @MiSimon.

Comment: capstonene: I think it is a great shame that your question is closed and locked. I found the question and the current answer very useful. Perhaps you could further edit as requested by @RoqueSosa to include what you do in Linux and what results you get from doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see all hashes that led to the current PCR values, you can use the WBCL (Windows Boot Configuration Logs) provided by the TPM and Windows (I think starting from Windows 8). These are logs that are generated by the TPM/Firmware and stored under "C:\Windows\Logs\MeasuredBoot". They contain every event that was sent to the TPM and every operation on a PCR register should be one of these events.

I am using the [TCGLogTools](https://github.com/mattifestation/TCGLogTools) to parse these logs. The format of the logs is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/tbs/nf-tbs-tbsi_get_tcg_log?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [here](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_PCClientSpecPlat_TPM_2p0_1p04_pub.pdf) if you wanted to write your own parser.

Comment: what is WBCL? i don't know

Comment: These are logs that are generated by the TPM/Firmware and stored under "C:\Windows\Logs\MeasuredBoot". They contain every event that was sent to the TPM and every operation on a PCR register should be one of these events.

Comment: C:\Windows\Logs\MeasuredBoot is empty for me

Comment: but my tpm is active

Comment: why is it empty?

Comment: i search more and i find tpmtool. but in my laptop tpmtool doesn't exist

Comment: do you know what should i do? tpmtool for windows doesn't exist in internet to download

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled in your UEFI/Bios? Does Windows known about your TPM (use tpm.msc)? Instead of tpmtool you can use the ibmtpm20tss (https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmtpm20tss/), it contains Windows cli programs for all available TPM commands.

Comment: secure boot is not supported in my laptop

Comment: thank you. how can i install it? i can't find out